# fineuploader - encoding special characters

Tags: fine-uploader

When i uploaded a file with the name "äüö.txt" the file on the ftp-server gets the name "-956.txt". This only happens when the name of the file contains special characters. How can I solve this problem?

HTML-Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="custom.fineuploader-4.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<script type="text/template" id="qq-template-manual-noedit">
<div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader">
    <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
        <span>Drop files here to upload</span>
    </div>
    <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
        <div>Upload a file</div>
    </div>
    <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
        <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
        <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
    </span>
    <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list">
        <li>
            <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
                <div class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
            </div>
            <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
            <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
            <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
            <a class="qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
            <span class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var manualuploader = $("#fine-uploader-fileUploadEmailCampaigns").fineUploader({
        autoUpload: false,
        multiple: false,
        template: "qq-template-manual-noedit",
        editFilename: {
            enabled: false
        },
        request: {
            endpoint: 'endpoint.php'
        },
    });

    $('#triggerUpload').click(function () {
        manualuploader.fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
    });


})
</script>

<title>Unbenanntes Dokument</title>
   <link href="custom.fineuploader-4.0.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>


</head>

<body>
  <div id="fine-uploader-fileUploadEmailCampaigns">
</div>
<div id="triggerUpload" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 10px;">Upload</div>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP-Code:

```
<?php

// Include the upload handler class
require_once "handler.php";


$uploader = new UploadHandler();

// Specify the list of valid extensions, ex. array("jpeg", "xml", "bmp")
$uploader->allowedExtensions = array(); // all files types allowed by default

// Specify max file size in bytes.
$uploader->sizeLimit = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // default is 10 MiB

// Specify the input name set in the javascript.
$uploader->inputName = "qqfile"; // matches Fine Uploader's default inputName value     bydefault

// If you want to use the chunking/resume feature, specify the folder to temporarily     save parts.
$uploader->chunksFolder = "chunks";

$method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
if ($method == "POST") {
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");

    // Call handleUpload() with the name of the folder, relative to PHP's getcwd()
    $result = $uploader->handleUpload("files");

    // To return a name used for uploaded file you can use the following line.
    $result["uploadName"] = $uploader->getUploadName();

    echo json_encode($result);
}
else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the locale ($LANG) you are using to write out the file does not match the locale of your OS. For example, to properly create a file with non-english characters in the name in my development environment (OS X, Java 7, IntelliJ) I need to be sure that the LANG environment variable associated with my JVM is "en_US.UTF-8", which matches the $LANG variable set in OS X.